# Question about the second derivative of a circle

Tags: calculus, circles, implicit-differentiation

I am trying to find the second derivative of a general circle but I can't seem to get the right answer.

My working goes as follows:

$$
(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=R^2
$$

$$
2(x-a)+2(y-b)*\frac{dy}{dx}=0
$$

$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{a-x}{y-b}
$$

I then applied the quotient rule:
$$
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{-(y-b)-\frac{dy}{dx}(a-x)}{(y-b)^2}
$$

$$
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{-(y-b)-\frac{a-x}{y-b}(a-x)}{(y-b)^2}
$$

$$
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{-(y-b)^2-(a-x)^2}{(y-b)^3}
$$

However, the correct answer was

$$
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-\frac{2}{y-b}
$$

I am assuming that that answer comes from

$$
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{-(y-b)-\frac{y-b}{a-x}(a-x)}{(y-b)^2}
$$

But I'm unsure why we multiply by $\frac{y-b}{a-x}$ and not $\frac{a-x}{y-b}$.

Comment: Your method is correct. You can further write it as $-\dfrac{R^2}{(y-b)^3}$

Comment: Where does the 'correct' answer ultimately come from?

Comment: The answer comes from the substitution of the value of the first derivative of another equation into it. I did not understand the marking scheme correctly. Sorry for the confusion. If you're interested, it comes from the first question in [this link](https://pmt.physicsandmathstutor.com/download/Maths/STEP/Papers/2010%20STEP%202.pdf).